# Windows Server 2008 and slow connecting to server with OS X

Tags: windows-server-2008, mac-osx, samba, file-sharing

I'm setting up a new Windows Server 2008 x64 file server. For Windows workstations everything works as it's supposed to but for OS X workstations it takes more than 30 seconds to even connect to the server. The funny part is that when the connection is established, everything works smoothly.

Also:

- On our old Windows Server 2003 file server there is no such a problem
- If I use Terminal.app & mount, the connection is established instantly
- I've tried googling the problem (of course) and tried stuff like disabling SMB 2.0 on the server side but without success

Has anyone else bumped into this problem and found a solution?

Comment: Having the exact same problem :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I totally forgot about this thread but after I recovered my account to comment another thread I remembered.

The solution was to create a file /Library/Preferences/edu.mit.Kerberos with content:

```
[libdefaults]
default_realm=foo.local
dns_fallback=no
```

You need to restart os x before it has any effect.

Answer (score 2):

The smells heavily of a DNS issue (30 second timeout, then working).  I would install wireshark and take a look at what the OS X system is trying to do for that 30 second window.  My bet is on DNS of some kind.

Comment: Oh, I should have mentioned this too: if I use server's ip to connect it's still slow.

Comment: Doesn't really rule out a DNS problem -- who knows if Mac OS X is trying to do a reverse and DNS and your DNS servers arn't responding, or it's ignoring the response for some reason.  Best to get a packet capture anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I found that when you click Go -> Connect to Server and put in smb://server/share it takes about 19 seconds to bring up the logon prompt.

If I click Go-> Connect to Server and put in smb://server:139/share it takes about 4 seconds to get the logon prompt.

Give this a try and see how it goes.

Adrian Page

Comment: Don't know if this works for 10.5 but on 10.6 it doesn't :(

Answer (score 0):

Any resolution to this one?
assuming it's a DNS issue, what is the resolution?
Is it simply that the proper reverse dns entries don't exist and need to be created?

Answer (score 0):

I can't +1 this because I am new here.
Someone please +1 this for me, as I too am having this annoying problem.

A network trace does show a few bits of DNS traffic taking 30 seconds...